# combining two neural networks into one

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, neural-network, fann

im trying to make a multithreaded extension to the [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) library. Because FANN is not [threadsafe](http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?t=149) i will do this:

1. divide the training set in *N* pieces (*N* is the number of CPUs)
2. copy the *ANN* to *N* copies
3. train each on his piece for 1 epoch
4. combine the *ANN* weights from the *N* copies
5. if not end conditions goto 2.

My question is: how can I combine the neural network weights into one. Can I just make mean from all?

Comment: That would be a new training algorithm and I think it wouldn't work as good as the existing algorithms. You could make N copies of the network and use each copy to calculate gradients of different training examples and then sum up these gradients to adjust the weights of all networks in the same way. Then you will have N identical networks.

Comment: I tried it and it goes good. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try what you suggested or did you try what I suggested? :D Btw. when you make a copy of all networks, are you really faster? The networks have to be big enough and the training has to be complex enough to compensate the initial computational cost.

Comment: I writen what you suggested. But it is just a little bit faster. but i must make copies of the ann. Or what you recommend? I also think i can use this algorithm with RPC and than i must also make copies.

Comment: When you don't make these copies, you won't be able to calculate the gradient correctly. If your problem is complex enough, i. e. the optimization needs many steps to converge, however, the overhead will be negligible.

Comment: Foremostly I think that from the mathematical standpoint that makes no sense / is not well defined. Your neural networks are representing potentially highly non linear functions -- what is the "combination" supposed to mean/ represent? It is defintely not just a composition / aggregation...